# Is there a module for Drupal 7 similar to OG Membership Expiration?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

[OG Membership Expiration](http://drupal.org/project/og_expire) is for Drupal 6. Is there a similar module for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to achieve?

Assuming that you want to unsubscribe an user after certain time:

In Drupal 7, OG integrates really well with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. It can fire many OG related action based on the condition / event you set.

You can use Rules Scheduler to schedule the action to be fired.

---

[image]

---

Furthermore, the [OG Role Reference Field](http://drupal.org/project/og_role_field) can:

- Grant a group role on a specific event
- Use rules_scheduler to remove a group role after a certain amount of time